# Is ASP.Net a scripting language or a framework?

Tags: asp.net

I came to an article in w3schools saying that asp.net is a server side scripting language. I used to believe that ASP.Net is a framework and not some scripting language. Please clarify my doubts regarding this.

Comment: "some scripting language"  you seem to feel that this mistake insults ASP.Net?  That a framework is good and a scripting language is bad?

Comment: I guess I am feeling it that way.

Answer (score 18):

It is a framework.

Since ASP.NET supports a number of languages it would be incorrect to say that it is, itself, "a language".

Answer (score 10):

Before .NET, people generally refer ASP as a script, because you need to write ASP script to get your webpage running on a ASP server.

However, after the introduction of ASP .NET, you can use other programming methods to build your webpage using the ASP .NET framework.

So for your answer, ASP .NET is a framework. For the old ASP, I don't know if you can classify it as a framework.

Comment: Well, ASP.NET allows multiple languages (C#, VB.NET, F#...) and has a common set of classes/methods.  Classic ASP allows multiple languages (VBScript, JScript) and has a common set of classes/methods.  Sounds similar to me.  The main difference is IL in .NET, instead of code text files with classic ASP.

Answer (score 3):

.NET is a framework.  ASP is (was) a server side scripting language.  ASP.NET now lets you use any  .NET language within the framework.

Correct me if im wrong, I don't use either.

Comment: it's wrong.  ASP is not a language, some may have referred to "classic asp" as a language, but that was technically vbscript.  ASP.Net supports many languages, most commonly VB.Net and C#

Comment: was correcting as you wrote that, although its probably still wrong i think ill just kill it

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET is a framework generally written in one of two languages - VB script or C#.

Answer (score -1):

ASP .NET is a server-side scripting language.  Your .aspx pages are just scripts that tell IIS how to render a page.  I'm not sure why this upsets you.

Comment: See above ...someone has written that it is a framework. I believe that it is a framework and not server side scripting language.

Comment: Honestly, what difference does it make?  The label you attach to it has no bearing on how it works.

Answer (score -1):

ASP.Net is a framework of ASP. Not the language itself.

Comment: Great, another duplicate answer.