# Is ASP.NET a language or not? Which is the fastest way to do something in it?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, vb.net

I am looking to learn ASP.NET but the information I have found about this subject get me a little confused. I thought ASP.NET was a language that you learned and then you program in it like is PHP, but what I have found is that you have to use VB or C#, Angular JS, and some other things to make something in ASP.NET.

So is ASP.NET a language or not? What is it exactly? Do I have to learn more than one language to do something in ASP.NET? which is the fastest way to start doing things in ASP.NET?

Comment: ASP.Net is not a language.  Read the documentation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is ASP.Net a scripting language or a framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4208227/is-asp-net-a-scripting-language-or-a-framework)

Comment: Classic ASP is a scripting language, whereas ASP.NET is a whole supporting platform (and not really related to Classic ASP at all). VB.NET is a language within ASP.NET.

Comment: @Paul - Classic ASP isn't a language either.  It's a technology whsich allows you to use VBScript or Javascript for server side scripting. And yes, it is very different to ASP.net

Comment: @John: Yep - I didn't think that through properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Microsoft docs:

> ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web
>   applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. You can also create Web
>   APIs, mobile sites, use real-time technologies like Web Sockets and
>   more!

You need to know C#, HTML, Javascript to get started with

For Additional Information:
http://www.asp.net/get-started